# ODP.NET Unmanaged and EntityFramework: error on ADO.NET Model creation

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net, odp.net, odac

I need to create a **db-first** model using ADO.NET and **ODP.NET Unmanaged** as provider in a ASP.NET MVC project.
I have already installed ODAC 12C package (12.2.0.1).
I have already installed EF6 nuget and referenced the DLLs Oracle.DataAccess and Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework in the project.
I have to use Oracle.DataAccess.Client because I need to define UDT, so I set up my web.config with:

```
 <configSection>
  ...
  <section name="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
 </configSection>
 <entityFramework>
  <providers>
   ...
   <provider invariantName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <providers>
 </entityFramework>
 <system.data>
   <DbProviderFactories>
     <add name="ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Unmanaged Driver" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=6.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />   
   </DbProviderFactories>
 </system.data>
```

When I try to add the ADO.NET model **I cannot select EF6** and the other option is not selectable and it generates an error:

*The project refers to the most recent version of EF. However, an EF database provider compatible with this version for the data connection in use could not be found. If a provider is already installed, make sure you have recompiled the project before performing this action. Otherwise, exit the wizard, install a compatible provider and recompile the project before performing this action.*

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is hard to understand what error message means. could you provide localization in English?

Comment: Translate error to english and post as text, not image

Comment: It used to work for me both ways, managed and unmanaged. But I believe we had oracle client installed with unmanaged, not just ODAC. And don't put too much faith in UDT. Because oracle only works with arrays in this sense.

Comment: This is self-explanatory. Version of EF in your project reference is not compatible with connection provider. If this is not the case and you have the correct provider - compile the project **before** performing the action, which causes this error